# insert values from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working in ORACLE DB for one of my projects. Now i have to insert the values to one table from 2 different tables.

Table created a below:

```
CREATE TABLE ATRB_VALUES_COUNT(MID VARCHAR(20),GID VARCHAR(20),SID VARCHAR(20),AID VARCHAR(20),AVID VARCHAR(20))
```

The values to be inserted are as below:

1. Get AID,AVID FROM Table called ATRB_VAL
2. Get Corresponding SID from AID from table ATRB
3. Get Corresponding MID,GID from table SB_ATRB

I have tried using union. But it din't work as there are different number of rows.

Comment: Why `SQL-Server`and `mysql` tag?

Comment: As is understand you, you have to use join, not union

Comment: Is the issue about the update or the way of finding the data to insert? that is: can you build a select query that gives you the data to be inserted?

Comment: Yes. In java I can but i am not that goot at sql.

Comment: Please post the structure of the involved tables, with a small set of sample data, and show what should the result be in the table ATRB_VALUES_COUNT. This way people will be able to build some code and try to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use join not union

```
insert into ATRB_VALUES_COUNT(MID,GID,SID,AID,AVID)
select a.AID,a.AVID, b.SID,c.MID,c.GID from ATRB_VAL as a, ATRB as b, SB_ATRB as c
```

(your join here, join 3 tables` ATRB_VAL , ATRB, SB_ATRB )